# $L^p$ implies continuity in some way

Tags: integration, continuity, lebesgue-integral, semigroup-of-operators

I want to prove the following,
$$
\lim_{t->0} \|T_p(t)f-f\|_p = 0,
$$
where $T_p(t)f(s) = \chi_{[0,e^{-t}]}(s)e^{t/p}f(se^t)$, with $f\in L^p([0,1])$ and $t>0$ and $s \in [0,1]$.
In fact, we have that,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{t->0} \|T_p(t)f-f\|_p & = \left( \lim_{t->0} \int_0^{e^{-t}} |e^{t/p} f(se^t) - f(s)|^p \, ds + \lim_{t->0} \int_{e^{-t}}^{1} |f(s)|^p \, ds \right)^{1/p} \\ &= (L_1+L_2)^{1/p}.
\end{aligned}
$$

On one hand as $f\in L^p([0,1])$ we can use dominated convergence theorem so, $L_2 = 0$. On the other hand $L_1 \leq 2^p\|f\|_p^p$ using Minkowski inequality therefore we can use again the dominated convergence theorem so,

$$
\begin{aligned}
L_1 & = \lim_{t->0} \int_0^{e^{-t}} | f(se^t) - f(s)|^p \, ds = \int_0^{1} \lim_{t->0} | f(u) - e^{-t/p}f(e^{-t}u)|^p \, du \\ &= \int_0^{1}  | f(u) - \lim_{t->0} f(e^{-t}u)|^p \, du.
\end{aligned}
$$

But here I face the problem to check that $\lim_{t->0} f(e^{-t}u) = f(u)$. Can I assure that this is true just because $f \in L^p([0,1])$?

Comment: Hint: linear combinations of indicators of intervals are dense in $L^p$.

Comment: Application of DCT is wrong because $\lim_{t->0} f(e^{-t}u)$ need not even exist.

Comment: @mihaild So the idea is to consider a function $f(u) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \chi_{I_k} (u)$, for a set of disjoint intervals $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^n$? But then I still don't know how to handle the composition.

Comment: How different can be integral of $\chi_{I_k}(u)$ and of $\chi_{I_k}(cu)$ when $c$ is close to $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I think I got the solution following the hints of @mihaild.

As we know the set of simple functions is dense in $L^p([0,1])$ we assume $f$ to be a simple function such that $f(u) = \sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_k \chi_{I_k}$ where $I_k=[a_k,a_{k+1})$ for $k \in \{1,2,\dots, n-1\}$ and $I_n=[a_n, a_{n+1}]$ with $a_0=0$ and $a_{n+1}=1$.

Therefore,

$$
\lim_{t\to 0} \int_0^1 |f(u)- e^{-t/p}f(e^{-t}u)|^p \, du = \lim_{t\to 0} \sum_{k=0}^n \int_{a_k}^{a_{k+1}} |f(u)- e^{-t/p}f(e^{-t}u)|^p \, du.
$$

Now we take $t$ as small as possible in order to assure that $a_{k-1} < e^{-t} a_k$ and that $a_k e^t< a_{k+1}$ for every $k$. Notice that this is possible because we are dealing with a finite amount of intervals. Thus,

$$
\lim_{t\to 0} \int_0^1 |f(u)- e^{-t/p}f(e^{-t}u)|^p \, du = \lim_{t\to 0} \sum_{k=0}^n \int_{a_k}^{a_k e^t } |\lambda_k- e^{-t/p} \lambda_{k-1}|^p \, du + \int_{a_k e^t}^{a_{k+1} } |\lambda_k- e^{-t/p} \lambda_{k}|^p \, du. 
$$

Where $\lambda_{-1}$ has to be understood as 0. Therefore,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{t\to 0} \int_0^1 |f(u)- e^{-t/p}f(e^{-t}u)|^p \, du & = \lim_{t\to 0} \sum_{k=0}^n a_k (e^t-1) | \lambda_k- e^{-t/p} \lambda_{k-1}|^p \\ & + \lim_{t\to 0} \sum_{k=0}^n (a_{k+1}-a_k e^t) |\lambda_k|^p|1- e^{-t/p}|^p\\
& = 0
\end{aligned}
$$

because in the first sum $e^t-1 \to 0$ as $t\to 0$ and in the second sum $1-e^{-t/p} \to 0$ as $t \to 0$.

This completes the proof.